# why the Initiator for example.swf is jquery-1.7.2.min in chrome Debugger Network Tab

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

Create a  html page,  load it, the code is :

```
<html>
<body>
<embed src='http://www.tizag.com/pics/example.swf'></embed>
</body>
</html>
```

see the picture below.
[image]
why the Initiator for example.swf  is jquery-1.7.2.min in chrome Debugger Network Tab